# Mysql recurring event parameters unknown

Tags: php, mysql, recurring

I have a MySQL database linked to a scheduling program. When an appointment is made, it is saved in a table called bookings. Even though the appointment is recurring, it is saved as one row. There is a formula that classifies what kind of recurring event it is (once a week, twice a week, once a month, etc.). From the manual, all the parameters are as follow:

- s - single event.
- d1 - every weekday.
- d - every day.
- wx-y - every x weeks on y. y corresponds to an 8 bit representation of
  the weekdays (Sunday is 1, Monday is 2, Tuesday is 4, Wednesday is 8,
  Thursday is 16, Friday is 32, Saturday is 64).
- mdx - every x months.
- mx-y-z - the xth y of every z months. x can be first (0), second (1),
  third (2), fourth (3) or last (4). y corresponds to the weekday (Sunday
  is 1, Monday is 2...Saturday is 7).

I created a PHP script that queries from the "bookings" table, but will only bring up the one appointment that shows the start date and end date. It is followed by a "freq" column, but I do not have a function or set of parameters that can translate that into querying all the recurring events from the start date to the end date. Also, the "startdate" and "enddate" columns are in "datetime" format (yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00).

P.S.
I can't post a picture because I am a new member, but I have 5 examples.

1. "w1-32" is once a week on Fridays;
2. "w1-8" is once a week on Wednesdays;
3. "d" is a daily appointment;
4. "d1" is only on weekdays; 
   5"w10-4" is every 10 weeks on Tuesdays.

Comment: So, you want to create a function, that will print a table of all the recurring events dates/times? Your input parameters look rather complex, so I am dubious, that we will write it for you.

Comment: I understand the complexity of it, which is why it's so frustrating. I've read almost every forum about recurring events, and in each one, the recurring values are split into different columns (ex. day frequency, month frequeny, etc.). In this one, all the values are put together, and I have yet to find an example that I can work from. All I want is to be pointed into the right direction, so that I can better learn myself.

Comment: ok, can you create 1 case of a simple recurring event, that you want to get a table for? Say, an event happens every day at certain time from date1 to date2? Then we'll increase the complexity and will solve the problem step by step.

Comment: Made mistakes on my last comment, had to delete it. John Doe is seen by Test Person on 9/4/2015 to 01/01/2016 every Friday at 8:00am to 9:00am. Once the information is sent, the MySQL table "bookings" will show one row with ID : 1; StartDate: 2015-09-04 00:00:00; StartTime: 2015-09-04 08:00:00; EndTime: 2015-09-04 09:00:00;Person: Person, Test; Freq: w1-32; EndDate: 2016-01-01 00:00:00; ClientID: Doe, John.